# g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'

Tags: dll, g++, mingw

I'm trying to link DLL with the following command:
`g++ -DFTCSPI_EXPORTS -shared -fpic -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ tmp\*.o "%D2XX_Dir%\ftcspi.lib" "%TclLibFile%" -o tmp\ftcspiif.dll`

I'm getting this error: `g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'`

I've checked I have libstdc++-6.dll in C:\MinGW\bin and my gcc version is 4.4.7.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That option came in GCC 4.5, so not available in 4.4 or earlier.

Comment: how do i upgrade GCC though?  I have unzipped a newer version of MinGW (g++) and added environment variable.  What else do i need to do?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1486691 guess help is late, but... I think what you did should be working. maybe you have multiple g++ installed now? in windows you can type in cmd.exe `where g++` and it should tell you the one or more directory containing `g++.exe` that is being used. if you see the one with the wrong version coming out on top, you need to check your PATH environment variable for the directory and the order (the first hit is used). if it's not the case, maybe you are not using g++ from command line but an ide? I need more information to help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my gcc version is 4.4.7.

The `-static-libstdc++` option was added in 2009 in this [patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-06/msg01635.html). The first released GCC version with this flag [is 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html).

Comment: how do i upgrade GCC though? I have unzipped a newer version of MinGW (g++) and added environment variable. What else do i need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Employed Russian stated, the -static-libstdc++ flag was added to GCC as of version 4.5.

Based on your comment to his answer though, if you're having trouble with installing/reinstalling/upgrading MinGW, I Highly suggest checking out http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ as they provide an up-to-date installer for the MinGW environment in both 32 & 64 bit flavors.
They also apply various patches to the environment but you can choose different versions of various packages to install if you have specific requirements or just want to stick with the vanilla MinGW environment.